# How to set proper values for -L and -l in make from a command output

Tags: linux, makefile

I can remember in a makefile on linux was used a command instead of stating the library and the path explicitly. It looked like this:

```
LIBS = `<command> Qt`
```

which created proper -L -l settings for Qt i.g. on the build-machine

Could you please tell me what was the command! 
I've at the moment a short-cut in my brain:-(

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the command pkg-config,

To list all libraries in available in pkg-config's path, use

```
pkg-config --list-all
```

In your case I would suggest trying,

```
pkg-config --libs Qt
```

Otherwise,

```
man pkg-config
```

is your friend.

Hope that helps!